# Configure and Run Maven 2 Core WAR Project in Eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, struts2

I know this is not a new question to you guys, who use Maven. But I'm really new to this. I have searched Stackoverflow and Google for hours, but didn't find a step-by-step working guide  (with screenshots).

I am using Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7 and now want to create a webapp with Maven. I have few basic needs to create this project. The m2e plugin's archetype seems most confusing to me. Although, it looks like a plug-and-play one, but I couldn't setup a struts2 project from archetype and build successfully.

1. The project should have strus2, spring and hibernate dependencies configured.
2. There should be a war and atleast one core module in the project.
3. I should be able to build and run it from Eclipse on Tomcat 7 server.

Please help guys. I think, there must be some ready-to-learn resource on the web. Please share it.

Comment: https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples/tree/master/Struts2Spring3Hibernate - here's a sample Maven project. You can find more examples here : https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples

Comment: Thanks mate for the links. These are really useful for me. But, how to configure and run this app on tomcat, from Eclipse workspace? Any clue on that?

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at the AppFuse modular archetype: `appfuse-modular-struts`

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List
http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+Struts+2

to have the list of available archetypes you can type: `mvn archetype:generate`

Comment: Yes I did. But AppFuse seems to import lot of unnecessary dependencies which I really don't need. To me, AppFuse looked much like a framework itself. Is it true? I can see, lot of JSPs got generated during build, automatically. So, I am looking for something simpler/cleaner.